# Fundamental Group of Orientable Surface

Tags: algebraic-topology

On p.51 Hatcher gives a general formula for the fundamental group of a surface of genus g.  I have one specific question, but would also like to check my general understanding of what's going on here.

First, as I understand it, we are associating the classes of loops in a-b pairs because: (a) we naturally associate them with the two classes of loops in the fundamental group of a single torus where they are abelian, and (b) more complex tori can be built up from single tori, and (c) any orientable surface of genus g>0 is homeomorphic to a torus of genus g.   (Please correct me if I am wrong in any of this.)

My specific question here concerns the relation.  If I understand the notation correctly, there is only one relation, namely that the composite product [a(1),b(1)] [a(2),b(2)]...[a(g),b(g)] = e ; where e is the identity.  But, don't we need a stronger relation?

Don't we also want to assure that all pairs of loops "factor out"?  I.e. That all pairs are abelian?  Don't we need [a(i),b(i)] [a(j),b(j)]= e, for all i and j ?

Equivalently, shouldn't the fundamental group have the presentation

<  a(1),b(1),a(2),b(2),..,a(g),b(g) |  [a(1),b(1)],[a(2),b(2)],...,[a(g),b(g)] >      ?

Comment: Nope, we don't. Try to actually draw the homotopies you think ought to exist for $g = 2$; they don't exist. What you've written down is the fundamental group of a wedge of $g$ tori, which is a different space.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan - Let me digest your comments for a few minutes...Are my (a), (b), and (c) statements correct, at least as informal statements of what's going on?

Comment: a) and b) are a little imprecise, and interpreted incorrectly lead you to your incorrect conclusion. You should distinguish carefully between taking connect sums and wedge sums. They are very different.

Comment: What then is the meaning/significance of the a-b pairing?

Comment: There are a couple of ways to answer that. One involves the cup product on cohomology.

Comment: My question is really just one of definitions.  Suppose I know the 2g generators, how do I pair them?  If I don't know how to pair them, I cannot use Hatcher's formula.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39158/discussion-between-user54301-and-qiaochu-yuan).